# Chat channel keeps loading forever

Tags: support, chat

I tried to visit the PHP room today on the Stackoverflow chat page and normally when I do so it will load for 2 to 3 seconds and then it loads. Just now I tried to enter it except that it keeps loading, it's trying to load for about 10 minutes now. The loading message is as follows:

> Loading [channel] Just a second...

I tried to check if the question was already posted or if a certain channel gets closed if there are no users in it but I couldn't find anything concrete. Not on Meta or Stackoverflow.

So I have a few questions:

- Does the channel close if there are less than x amount of users? If so I would like a notification that the channel is currently closed to avoid confusion. [**Will these rooms last forever**](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#retention)
- Does the client require any special plugins for the chat room to load? For example: Flashplayer/Silverlight. **They don't, no need for plugins.**

I am using `Mozilla Firefox v17.0.1` on a `Windows 7` machine.

Comment: recently, there was a DDoS attack going on by some Indian teenager. That may be the cause for the slowness too I think ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No plugins are required. Inactive channels eventually do get cleaned up, but for a popular room like the PHP room that won't be the case for quite some time. See [Will these rooms last forever?](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#retention) in the chat FAQ; if the room went idle for 14 days it'll be marked as 'frozen' (and will not be deleted).

Try a force-reload, you are probably just experiencing a network hickup somewhere. Chat rooms, including the PHP room, load fine for me.

Comment: I tried multiple reloads and I restarted my browser as well, no luck yet. I also didn't come across the page you linked me before, it's a bit hard to find. I would upvote, but I lack the reputation.

Comment: @MarioS: It's linked from the `chat.stackoverflow.com` pages (`faq` in the top bar); you can also find it in each room (bottom right, `faq` again, and the `help` popup also points to it for more info).

Comment: It's not listed in the FAQ, hence my statement about being hard to find.

Comment: @MarioS: *what* is not listed in the FAQ? Note that I linked you to a section in the FAQ.

Comment: Ah yes you're right. I misread it however the problem still persists. I cannot enter the chat room.

Comment: It seems the problem magically solved itself. Didn't update anything but it seems to work fine now. As you suggested a network hiccup probably.